# ggplot multiple line charts on top of each other (with different y-axis scales)

Tags: ggplot2, charts, line, linechart

I would like to show multiple linecharts together in one chart (like you see in the picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49I9x.png)). but the values of each charts are different (range from 50'000 to 1'200'000) so they look twisted. Is there a way to plot them without 1 y-axis for all of them together?

I hope you can melp me thanks a lot